# Why unable to save image to db in django?

Tags: django

I am new to Django and trying to save image to database i have written few lines code, which are not showing any error but are not able to save image to database.

**View:-**

```
def IndexView(request):
    print("index view..")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("post")
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print("form {}".format(form))
        if form.is_valid():
            print("valid..")
            form.save()

    form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

**my template:-**

```
<div class="container">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token%}
        <hr><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="" id="" required/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn danger" value="Upload">
    </form>
</div>
```

**model:-**

```
class MyImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="myimage")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="")
```

Hope to here from you soon
Thanks in advance

Comment: The "name" attribute of the file input in your template must match the name of the image field on your ImageForm form. Currently it's empty

Comment: Do you have model of this if yes please share

Comment: yes i sharing the model.

Comment: @sarangkkl i have added the model above, please have a look..

Comment: @lain Shelvington thanks you were write..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token%}
        <hr><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="" required/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn danger" value="Upload">
    </form>
</div>

def IndexView(request):
    print("index view..")
    if request.method == 'POST':
       image=request.FILES.get('image') 
       name=///give a nmae to your image
       x = MyImage.objects.create(image=image,name = name)
       x.save()
       return render(request, "index.html")
```

by this way you can see your image in the admin panel if you get any error assking for module install pillow just search google